# 最適化を無効化(-O0)すると動作しないアプリケーション？

Tags: c, gcc, gentoo

Gentoo linuxのドキュメントに下記のような説明がありました。
字義通り解釈すると「コンパイル時最適化を無効(`-O0`)にすると正常動作しないアプリケーションがある」とのことですが、実際にそのようなパッケージ（アプリケーション）は存在するのでしょうか？

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GCC_optimization

> `-O0:` This level (that is the letter "O" followed by a zero) turns off optimization entirely and is the default if no `-O` level is specified in CFLAGS or CXXFLAGS. This reduces compilation time and can improve debugging info, but **some applications will not work properly without optimization enabled.** This option is not recommended except for debugging purposes.

個人的には、最適化無効状態で正常動作しない＝そもそも壊れたプログラムという感覚なのですが...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

StackExchange の Unix&Linux コミュニティで [Linux cannot compile without GCC optimizations; implications?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153788/linux-cannot-compile-without-gcc-optimizations-implications) というのを見つけました。これによると、Linux のカーネルのビルドは、不要なコードの削除や関数のインライン展開などのGCC の最適化に依存しており、`-O0` だとビルドに失敗するそうです。

Comment: accept answerは迷ったのですが、リンク先の情報でこちらとさせてもらいました。

Answer (score 16):

パッと思いつく例としては、末尾最適化を前提とした再帰呼び出しでしょうか。
この場合もちろんコンパイルは通りますが、実行時には再帰呼び出しによりコールスタックを食い潰しスタックオーバーフローを引き起こします。

Comment: +1; 関数の再帰呼び出しと末尾呼び出し最適化は、妥当なCコードだが最適化OFFで動かなかくなる（可能性のある）具体例ですね。

Answer (score 10):

x86ではdoubleの演算はFPUに乗る時に80bitに拡張されます(FPU制御レジスタの設定によりますが、Linuxではデフォルトで拡張されるようになっていたはず)。計算の途中結果を一時変数に代入している場合、最適化無しだと代入の際に64bitに丸められてそれが続きの計算で使われますが、最適化ありだとFPUのレジスタに乗っている80bitの値をそのまま使われ、演算結果が異なる可能性があります。通常のプログラムでは浮動小数点数演算の誤差として片付けられるのですが、まれにこの差が問題となることがあります。

実例として、浮動小数点数の正確かつ最適な表示 (与えられた浮動小数点数が表現し得る幅の中で、最も短い10進数表記を求める)アルゴリズムは、64bitのdoubleを扱うためには64bitより大きい精度を必要とします。計算途中で10倍する際に、仮数部の有効数字が1bit余計に必要になるためです。最適化無しで中間結果をdouble型変数に代入すると途中で丸めが入っておかしくなりますが、中間結果が80bitのまま保持されると正しい結果が得られます。Scheme処理系SCMがかつてそのような実装になっていました(参考:[1](https://practical-scheme.net/wiliki/wiliki.cgi?Gauche%3A%E6%8B%A1%E5%BC%B5%E6%B5%AE%E5%8B%95%E5%B0%8F%E6%95%B0%E7%82%B9%E6%BC%94%E7%AE%97%E3%81%AE%E8%AC%8E)。現在の実装は多倍長整数を使っているのでこの問題はもうありません。)

もちろんコード作法的には良くない実装です。コンパイラとプロセッサを決め打ちできる案件ならともかく、今はデスクトップではx86_64の方が主流になり「最適化で80bitのまま保持されることをあてにする」という手法自体obsoleteと考えて良いと思います。

Comment: 浮動小数点数の演算精度で"not work properly"とまで言い切るのはちょっと無理があるかもしれませんが、printfで値を表示したらなぜか計算結果が変わった不具合とかの原因ですね… http://0xcc.net/blog/archives/000164.html

Comment: 32bit floatについてもFPU（80bit）とSSE（32bit）とで演算結果が異なるという問題もありますね。

Comment: @yohjpさん、固定長の有限浮動小数点数というのは対応する実数と誤差範囲がきちんと定まっているので「正確かつ最適な入出力」というのも定義できます。その仕様のもとで異なる出力が得られたら困ります。ここに書いた件も、テストが失敗することから発見したものでした。もちろん、そういう仕様を必要としない用途の方が多いですが。

Comment: 浮動小数点数だから誤差はつきものと軽く(？)捉えていたのですが、確かに言われてみればですね。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

抽象的な回答になってしまいますが。

規格上、未定義・不定・実装依存とされてしまうような書き方をしていると、コンパイラやプラットフォームが変わって動作しなくなるというのはありがちで、最適化オプションの指定によっても変わるというのは十分あり得る話だと思います。

代入文の左辺と右辺の評価順、関数の引数の評価順 (いずれも不定) あたりは、優秀なプログラマでもついやってしまうようで、mrubyでもあったようです。
https://codeiq.jp/magazine/2013/12/3556/
(ただ、これが最適化オプションの違いで起きるかは不明です。)

ちなみに、「最適化が無効になっていると動作しないアプリがある」ですよね? (どちらかといえば、最適化によって壊れることの方が多いですが。)

Comment: 未定義(undefined)は論外として、未規定(unspecified)と実装依存(implementation-defined)がコンパイラの最適化有無で変化するというのは、原則論としては受け入れ難いですね。リンク先は確かに未定義動作に依存しているので、実際に起きても不思議ではないと思います（検知・修正するのは簡単じゃないですが…）